# How not to close the browser in Selenide?

Tags: java, selenium, selenide

I want to write code and visually look at the results.
I need to be on the site for an unlimited amount of time.

Can I somehow disable closing the browser after going to the site?

```java
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        Configuration.browser = "chrome";
        Configuration.driverManagerEnabled = true;
        Configuration.browserSize = "1920x1080";
        Configuration.headless = false;
        Selenide.open(BASE_URL);
        // Here the browser is automatically closed after a couple of seconds
```

Comment: In Selenium with Python, to prevent the browser from automatically closing, we have use:    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True).   Try this logic in Selenide.

Answer (score 0):

That's easy, add this configuration. Browser will remain open after test.

```
Configuration.holdBrowserOpen=true
```